# How can I write a Publishers.CombineLatest that uses variadic generics in Swift 5.9?

Tags: swift, generics, combine, variadic

Now that Swift 5.9 includes support for variadic generics, I was hoping to get a `Publishers.CombineLatest` implementation using it, but there isn't one.

I figure we can make our own, but I don't even know where to begin. Any ideas?

Comment: No, parameter packs are not fully-fledged variadic generics. You cannot do this yet. The first step would be to declare a type parameter pack where all the types conform to `Publisher` and have the same `Failure` type, but you cannot do that. `struct CombineLatest<each P: Publisher, Failure: Error> where repeat (each P).Failure == Failure` gives "Same-element requirements are not yet supported".

Comment: Ah, bummer. I guess I didn't read the fine print. Thanks for the explanation.